# Using @InjectMocks to replace @Autowired field with a mocked implementation

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, spring-boot, mockito

I want to replace an autowired class of a service in my spring boot app with a mocked implementation of that class that I created specifically for testing.

I chose to create this mocked implementation because the behaviour of this class is too complicated to mock using mockito as it requires multiple other mocks itself.

I am not able to work out how to inject this mocked implementation into the service.

Here is a minimal example of the situation:

```
@Service
public class ServiceIWantToTestImpl implements ServiceIWantToTest{

    @Autowired
    ComplicatedDependency complicatedDependency;

    @Override
    public void methodUsingDependency(){
        String string = complicatedDependency.doSomething();
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}


public class MockComplicatedDependency implements ComplicatedDepencency{

    public MockComplicatedDependency(...){
        // Inject other mocked objects into this mock
    }

    public String doSomthing(){
        // This would be a mocked version of this function for testing
        return "test";
    }

}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestingTheService(){
    @InjectMock
    private static ServiceIWantToTest serviceIWantToTest = new ServiceIWantToTestImpl();

    @Mock
    ComplicatedDependency mockComplicatedDependency;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init(){
        mockComplicatedDependency = new MockComplicatedDependency(...);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAttempt(){
        serviceIWantToTest.methodUsingDependency();  // This method calls complicatedDependency.doSomething() which does not run the mocked version in MockComplicatedDependency which I wanted to inject, and would always return null instead of the "test" string I put in this example.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have to use Mockito annotations to setup dependencies for the class under test?

**If that is not the main constraint** why not just do the plain simple setup and introduce a constructor or a setter in `ServiceIWantToTestImpl` class for the `ComplicatedDependency` field and set the dependency in your test setup directly to whatever impl of ComplicatedDependency you like e.g.:

```
@Service
public class ServiceIWantToTestImpl implements ServiceIWantToTest {

    @Autowired
    ComplicatedDependency complicatedDependency;

    public ServiceIWantToTestImpl() {

    }

    public ServiceIWantToTestImpl(ComplicatedDependency complicatedDependency) {
        this.complicatedDependency = complicatedDependency;
    }

    @Override
    public void methodUsingDependency(){
        String string = complicatedDependency.doSomething();
        System.out.println(string);
    }
}

public class TestingTheService {

    private static ServiceIWantToTestImpl serviceIWantToTest;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init(){
        serviceIWantToTest = new ServiceIWantToTestImpl(new MockComplicatedDependency());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAttempt() {
        serviceIWantToTest.methodUsingDependency();
    }

}
```

That is one way.

To make it work with Mockito, You *could* to use @Spy instead of @Mock like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestingTheService {

    @InjectMocks
    private static ServiceIWantToTestImpl serviceIWantToTest = new ServiceIWantToTestImpl();

    @Spy
    private static ComplicatedDependency complicatedDependency = new MockComplicatedDependency();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testAttempt() {
        serviceIWantToTest.methodUsingDependency();
    }

}
```

Though this is a bit of a hack. I strongly recommend that you read the JavaDoc of the @Spy annotation and make sure it's expected use is what you really need for your test.

Comment: I tried using @Spy as you suggested and it works great. Thanks! I don't really want to introduce a constructor just for testing, I want to let spring handle the dependency injection in the application.

Comment: Actually, constructor-level injection is the recommended approach, field-level injection is generally discouraged

Comment: As @Milos mentioned, Spring has been recommending constructor injection already for a decade now: http://spring.io/blog/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/ . Nobody should be using field injection anymore.

Comment: Aha, very interesting! Thanks for the information, I'm a self-taught programmer so there are a lot of holes in my knowledge.